# Django module object is not iterable

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm currently trying to build a blog using Django. I've been facing this error for a few hours now. I'm not quite sure if this has anything to do with the directories but the error occurs when I try to register my model in the admin.py file.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post

# Register models
admin.site.register(Post)
```

The directories look as follows:

```
blog
   models
        Post
        Category
   admin.py
settings
static
templates
```

Trace:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7ffb589a67b8>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 112, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 248, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 225, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 120, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/apps.py", line 23, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/hallak/Projects/hallak.io/hallak_blog/admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    admin.site.register(Post)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/sites.py", line 102, in register
    for model in model_or_iterable:
TypeError: 'module' object is not iterable
```

Post:

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone


class Post(models.Model):
    # Auto-generated ID
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    # Title
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    # Slug
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)

    # Content
    body = models.TextField()

    # Timestamps
    created_on = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    published_on = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    # Category
    category = models.ForeignKey('.Category', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    # Author
    author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)

    # Publish post
    def publish(self):
        self.published_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Category:

```
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    # Auto-generated ID
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    # Title
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    # Slug
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)

    # Timestamps
    created_on = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The error is happening here: https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/sites.py#L100-L101

Whenever I comment the register line everything works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of writing "from .models import Post" you should write "from .models.Post import Post".

First "Post" is a modulename (file name), second one is a class name.

Comment: This solved the first error but generates another one `ERRORS:
hallak_blog.Post.category: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model '.Category', which is either not installed, or is abstract.
hallak_blog.Post.category: (fields.E307) The field hallak_blog.Post.category was declared with a lazy reference to '.category', but app '' isn't installed.`

Comment: model "Category" should be imported in the Post.py module. You are using name "Category" in the Post class, but it's not defined. from ".Category" import "Category".

Comment: You really shouldn't be putting your models in separate files. Although that can be made to work, it's confusing for someone who's new to Python and Django. It's also the cause of both your problems. Move them both back into a single models.py.

Comment: @MihanEntalpo So I merged both models back into models.py in the root directory to avoid confusion so admin.py and models.py are in the same directory but now `from .models import Post` doesn't work.

Comment: @hallaksec, and what problem python is displaying now?

Comment: @MihanEntalpo `ValueError: Invalid model reference 'hallak_blog.models.models'. String model references must be of the form 'app_label.ModelName'.` I'm using `from .models import Post`

Comment: @hallaksec "String model reference must be of the form ...." - means, that you have some string reference to model, and it's malformed. Could you push your actual code to git, and let me see?

Comment: @hallaksec try to modify your import in the admin.py. Add "Category" to the imported classes list, and then, try to register it (just for experiment), but before you register the Post class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161906/discussion-between-mihanentalpo-and-hallaksec).